# Qual é a finalidade do diretório "system" do micro-framework Inphinit?

Tags: php, inphinit

Pretendo usar o  [Inphinit micro-framework](https://github.com/inphinit/inphinit) em um projeto meu, mas antes de tudo preciso conhecer mais a respeito dele.

Sendo assim, criei um projeto de exemplo só para ir me familiarizando com suas características, entretanto, me surgiu uma dúvida em relação a um diretório que ele possui, que é o diretório **system**. Veja abaixo sua estrutura:

```
C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\HELLOINPHINIT\SYSTEM
├───application
│   ├───Config
│   ├───Controller
│   │   └───Users
│   ├───Model
│   └───View
│       ├───debug
│       └───foo
├───boot
└───vendor
    ├───composer
    └───inphinit
        └───framework
            └───src
                ├───Experimental
                │   └───Routing
                └───Inphinit
                    └───Routing
```

Acima estão os diretórios e subdiretórios do diretório system.

## Pergunta

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade do diretório **system** e qual é a importância que ele tem em relação a minha aplicação web?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O framework é meu e realmente tem motivo para tudo no como ele foi feito, infelizmente eu ainda não tive um tempo para documenta-lo de maneira que possa torna-lo proveitoso, vou tentar não me demorar na explicação e conforme o tempo editarei para agregar detalhes.

### Como outros frameworks funcionam

Para explicar o porque da estrutura ser esta:

```
./public_html
  ├───index.php
  └───system
      ├───application
      ├───vendor
      └───boot
```

Precisa entender como outros frameworks funcionam, a maior parte deles usa um diretório dentro da pasta do projeto chamado `./public` (laravel) ou `./webroot` (cakephp), etc. Isto exige que no momento de publicar um projeto online o desenvolvedor/administrador aponte para pasta estas pastas como sendo a `root` do site, isto as vezes é trabalhoso e por vezes em servidores mais limitados como os servidores shared é necessário mover o conteudo para `public_html` e pegar o resto do conteudo e colocar fora, o que pode eventualmente confundir um pouco para quem não tem experiencia.

Claro que basta seguir a orientação nos sites que tem a documentação, mas ainda sim noto muitas pessoas com dificuldade nisto.

### Como funciona a estrutura

A minha ideia no framework foi que você pudesse facilmente mover o conteudo de um lugar para o outro sem precisar ajustar nada, então a estrutura ficou assim:

```
./home/user/public_html
 ├───index.php # Arquivo principal que inicia tudo
 └───system # Pasta aonde ficarão os dados e funcionalidades
     ├───application # Pasta dos Controllers, Models e Views
     ├───vendor # Pasta aonde fica o nucleo do framework e frameworks de terceiros instalados via composer
     └───boot # arquivos de inicialização da aplicação, "cache" dos namespaces
```

Alguns podem indagar que ao deixar a pasta `system` dentro de `public_html` e `www` pode ser inseguro, em muitos casos isto seria realmente correto, mas o sistema usa rotas e ignora o acesso a pasta `./system`, eu fiz uma série de perguntas sobre segurança, bloqueios e/ou tentativas de causar alguma falha, basicamente o .htaccess esta assim:

```
RewriteRule "^system/" "index.php" [L]
```

E se o mod_rewrite estiver desativado o apache irá emitir o erro `500 Internal Error Server`.

Ainda existe a pasta `system/storage` que contem qualquer tipo de dados usado na aplicação, em ambientes *like-unix* ele ainda força usar [`0600` como permissão](https://github.com/inphinit/framework/blob/master/src/Inphinit/AppData.php#L88):

```
$r = is_dir($fullName) ? true : mkdir($fullName, 0600, true);
```

A ideia toda é simplificar o entendimento ao máximo de quem está começando, por exemplo, ao invés de adicionar as configurações de rotas em um arquivo em um subpasta eu procurei deixar livre para desenvolver como quiser dentro de dois arquivos o `system/main.php` e o `system/dev.php`, o main.php é o arquivo principal de todo projeto junto aos controllers e views, o dev.php só é usado se estiver em modo de desenvolvimento.

No inicio eu pensei em fazer algo como:

```
  ./home/user/public_html
    ├───index.php
    ├───application
    ├───vendor
    └───boot
```

O que simplificaria, mas eu teria que fazer isto no no .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule "^(application|vendor|boot)/" "index.php" [L]
```

E também pensei que talvez o desenvolvedor pudesse fazer alguma confusão entre o main.php e index.php, fora que existe a possibilidade do desenvolvedor acreditar que as pastas estão inseguras e então mover mais facilmente toda aplicação sem precisar mover uma pasta por uma, fazendo algo assim:

```
  ./home/user
    ├───system
    │   ├───main.php
    │   ├───vendor
    │   └───boot
    └───public_html
        └───index.php
```

E trocando no [index.php](https://github.com/inphinit/inphinit/blob/master/index.php#L11) o valor de `INPHINIT_PATH` de:

```
define('INPHINIT_PATH', INPHINIT_ROOT . 'system/');
```

Para:

```
define('INPHINIT_PATH', INPHINIT_ROOT . '../system/');
```

### Resumindo

A pasta `./system` é o projeto de verdade e o que esta fora dela é apenas o que inicia ela, podendo ser o `index.php` ou servidor [*built-in server*](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.webserver.php) com `server.bat` ou `server.sh`.

Comment: +1 ... massa ... uma pergunta ainda não tem um `ORM` embutido?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não tem ainda, pois ORM é algo muito complexo para dispor de tempo, mas é possivel usar qualquer framework de ORM junto com este, através do composer, um exemplo é o http://propelorm.org ou doctrine. A ideia do framework é poder usar com qualquer coisa, mas tenho sim intuito de criar um ORM proprio no futuro :)