# Qual é a finalidade da pasta Model do framework Inphinit?

Tags: php, inphinit

No [Inphinit micro-framework](http://inphinit.github.io/) existe a pasta Model que fica dentro da pasta [application](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173350/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-diret%C3%B3rio-system-do-micro-framework-inphinit), e nela é onde ficam as classes, mas eu estou muito confuso em relação a essas classes.

Veja uma classe dentro da pasta Model:

```
<?php
namespace Model;

class User extends \Inphinit\Experimental\Model
{
}
```

## Dúvidas

1. Eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade da pasta Model?
2. Para que serve as classes da pasta Model e qual a importância que
   essas classes tem em relação ao funcionamento da minha aplicação Web?

<sup>*Se puder me explicar com exemplos práticos vai ser mais fácil para eu entender*.</sup>

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vai ser capaz de explicar melhor :P, mas se for seguindo o padrão [tag:mvc] (Model, View, Controller), Model geralmente abriga as consultas ao banco de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O jHertel já deu uma breve introdução ao que é o MVC, algumas perguntas que podem lhe ajudar sobre isto especificamente:

- [Onde deve ficar a regra de negócio no padrão MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114084/3635) (talvez a mais importante para entender aqui na pergunta)
- [Tratar regras de negócio no model é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94065/3635)
- [O que é a View no padrão MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168246/3635)
- [O que é MVC(Model, View, Controller)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/3635)
- [O que é MVP e MVVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/3635)
- [Alternativas ao MVC para aplicações Web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4474/3635)
- [Como e para que usar MVC no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114824/3635)

Do meu ponto de vista resumido, MVC não tem um padrão especifico, na verdade de muitas maneiras você pode fazer o uso disto e atingir o mesmo resultado, podendo ser estrito ou não, o inphinit não é estrito (rigoroso), na verdade é bem "livre", com exceção dos `Controllers` que quase sempre são obrigatórios (apesar de suportar [`Closures`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)).

Então o MVC é um modo de se organizar e não uma tecnologia, do meu ponto de vista, o MVC mais comum representado é este:

[image: mvc]

O inphinit segue muitas coisas semelhantes a outros frameworks conhecidos, tendo a pasta e namespace para `Controller` e `Model` (`View` não tem namespace), esta classe que você postou foi um dos exemplos experimentais que estava realizando:

```
<?php
namespace Model;

class User extends \Inphinit\Experimental\Model
{
}
```

No momento removi a classe `\Inphinit\Experimental\Model`, não por ser errado, mas por não atingir ainda o que espero, do meu ponto de vista Models não tem nada haver com banco de dados, eles apenas usam os dados contidos neles, o objetivo do Model é definir as "regras de negócio", fazendo uso assim de qualquer tipo de informação, tendo a capacidade de obtê-las, atualizar e deletar, mas tudo isso tendo regras.

No entanto creio que um Model, seja aonde for nunca deve manipular coisas diretamente, tipo enviar dados para o ouput, ou enviar resposta, ele deve enviar apenas a resposta (se houver) para o controller e o controller deve se encarregar do resto (claro que me baseio nisto com a experiencia que tive com ferramentas totalmente diferentes, como disse MVC nem sempre é igual em dois lugares ou frameworks diferentes).

Na maior parte dos frameworks que noto o Model é usado meramente como instrumento de conexão com o banco e algumas regras acabam caindo dentro do `Controller`.

Quando idealizei o inphinit ele tinha 5 objetivos:

1. Suportar o PHP 5.3
2. Gastar o minimo de memória possível
3. Ser o mais rápido possível sem existir inúmeros ciclos dentro do núcleo.
4. Ser mais simples possível para o aprendizado
5. Suportar bibliotecas de terceiros (3rdparty) que seja instalado via composer

Com este último objetivo é que chegamos ao `namespace Model;` e a pasta `system/application/Model/`, o framework não possui nada como *migration*, *conexão* e *sqlbuilder*, mas isto não quer dizer que você não possa instalar coisas de terceiros, existem frameworks que inclusive já usei com ele como:

- http://www.doctrine-project.org
- http://propelorm.org
- https://github.com/taq/torm
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent (dei uma breve explicação aqui [Existe alguma forma de usar Laravel Eloquent no microframework Silex?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177879/3635))

Ou seja o foco da pasta e namespace `Model` é o mesmo que da maioria dos frameworks, no entanto pode-se usar com **o ORM que desejar** ou **como desejar**

> Assim que possível irie adicionar um passo-a-passo de um ou mais frameworks para trabalhar com o namespace `Model`.

Answer (score 8):

> Eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade da pasta Model?

Normalmente em aplicações web utilizamos uma forma de organização do projeto chamada MVC. (**M**odel-**V**iew-**C**ontroller)

- **Model** Classes relacionadas a banco de dados e regras de negócio
- **View** Templates com HTML/Linguagem de template para visualizar o conteúdo da sua aplicação.
- **Controller** Classes que fazem o controle da aplicação. É como se fossem uma *cola* entre os modelos e as views. É geralmente nos controllers que a aplicação verifica se é um GET,POST, etc e toma as decisões sobre qual View mostrar, como processar os dados, etc.

> Para que serve as classes da pasta Model

Neste modelo de organização as classes que correspondem as regras de negócio e ligação com o banco de dados costumam ficar na pasta `Model`.

É uma forma de organização e você pode optar por segui-la ou não.

> e qual a importância que essas classes tem em relação ao funcionamento da minha aplicação Web?

A importância dos modelos é deixar mais claro e separado as regras de negócio e de banco de dados do restante da aplicação.

Atualmente o MVC é muito utilizado em frameworks, apesar de eu nunca ver uma estrutura exatamente igual ou padronizada. Isto serve mais como uma linha de guia para manter a organização, mas você sempre é livre para mudar e usar conforme a sua necessidade.

Comment: Só pra completar um pouco mais a explicação do controller, da forma como entendo ele: O controller é responsável por responder às requisições ao servidor. Saber se é um GET, um POST ou outra coisa e agir para responder às requisições acessando os models e retornando as views.

Comment: @cav_dan, editei a pergunta e adicionei uma explicação um pouco melhor do controller. Obrigado pela dica :)